# What is a good way to base the enabled state of the OK button in a dialog on valid control entries

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0, wpf-controls, wpf-4.0

Even if I associate the button with a class derived from `ICommand`, I am still left with figuring out how the button should trigger the `CanExecute` method and refresh its enabled state. I do know about the `CanExecuteChanged` event for which a button with an associated command registers, but see the following paragraph for why this is troublesome.

On a plain old dialog consisting of some 10-15 controls, it seems haphazard to have to process every change notification for every single one of those controls, triggering the `CanExecuteChanged` event on the button's command, causing the button's enabled state to be affected by the `CanExecute` method's return value. Even stating what needs to be done in the last sentence was quite cumbersome.

There must be a better way of coding a WPF dialog, so that the confirmation button (e.g., OK) is grayed out until all controls have valid information and is enabled at that point in time (i.e., when all controls are properly filled in). Sample code, ideas and pointers to articles would be immensely appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything haphazard here.  Since your condition is "**all** controls have valid information", this can occur after any control is edited, and therefore you need to listen to change notifications from all controls.

Comment: But, doing this by adding a "changed" handler to each control manually (i.e., within the XAML) seems at the very least to be error prone. Especially, since the handlers indicating change and the properties that set them differ from control to control. I am stuck with some N event handlers, depending on how many different control types I use all calling a common handler which finally raises the CanExecuteChanged event. There must be a more automated way to do this within WPF itself. Surely, this validation requirement is commonplace enough for some functionality built into WPF to be applicable.

Comment: @Michael: If you don't like wiring up handlers in XAML, do it from code.  You should be able to loop through all controls very easily.

Comment: But either way, the number of handlers is still the same and a handler is still required per control type. I think it's actually easier from XAML, but still too error prone and cumbersome than having something built into each control, like a validator that can for example signal when the control has valid input or something. This would seem preferable even if I have to code the validator once for each control type to help it determine what's valid and what's not. I could do it once maybe and stick it in as a style or something that affects all controls of its type.

Answer (score 0):

> On a plain old dialog consisting of some 10-15 controls, it seems
>   haphazard to have to process every change notification for every
>   single one of those controls,

I don't think so. Every Textbox, checkbox changed event is handled by the same handler, say `SetState()`, which calculates the overall state of the dialog. Every time a control is edited, the entire state is recalculated.

> until all controls have valid information

Then that object would have a boolean property `EnableOKButton`, let's say, which is set according to the updated state. Then that property is bound to the button's `Enabled` property so it automagically changes - without dealing with extraneous events.

Comment: You can't use the same handler for all of the changed events, because different controls use different delegate types for their changed event requiring handler functions with differing prototypes. In the best case you can have one handler per control type, which is exactly what I do, and then have each of these handlers call you central handler which validates the content of each and every control, triggering the CanExecuteChanged event of the command associated with the OK button when finished (whether or not CanExecute has actually transitioned from false to true or vice versa).

Comment: And, by the way, even with an Enabled property that triggers the button's enabled state, you would still need to somehow tell the button to re-evaluate its dependency on said property. Therefore, you would most likely need a dependency property and not a plain old ordinary C# property. In the end this is arguably more complex than having a command object associated with the button and its coresponding CanExecuteChanged event for which the button is automatically registered.

Comment: The point is that with many event/handlers doing bits of state change - and the state-bits are inter-related -  and the user triggers events in who knows what order -- then the only way to guarantee consistent/valid state is to recalculate the entire state in all cases.

I'm totally freaking guessing here but I wonder if implementing Command pattern at such a fine grained level isn't way over engineering. I apologize in advance for possibly trivializing a complex problem.